# Are there any differences between accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0) and accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0ll) in C++?

Tags: c++, stl

When I write
`long long sum = accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0);`
or
`long long sum = accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0ll);`
both give me the same result (where `a` is `std:: vector<int> a(n)`).

So why use `0ll` instead of only `0` ?

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
const int MAX = 1e6;
int main()
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
//  freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
#endif

    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> a(n);
    vector<int> cnt(MAX + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
        ++cnt[a[i]];
    }
    long long sum = accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0ll);
    vector<int> ans;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        sum -= a[i];
        --cnt[a[i]];
        if (sum % 2 == 0 && sum / 2 <= MAX && cnt[sum / 2] > 0)
        {
            ans.push_back(i);
        }
        sum += a[i];
        ++cnt[a[i]];
    }

    cout << ans.size() << endl;
    for (auto it : ans)
        cout << it + 1 << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And here is [the same code on OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/3XOSoz5Y2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) is a template, when being passed `0` (which is supposed to be the initial value of the sum), the 2nd template parameter will be deduced as `int`, then the sum is performed on `int`, the return type is `int` too. Then in `long long sum = accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0);`, the returned `int` is converted to `long long` and assigned to `sum`.

On the other hand, `accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0ll);` performs sum on `long long` and returns a `long long`.

If the sum won't cause overflow on `int`, you'll get the same result on both cases. Otherwise, the 2nd one should be perferred.

Comment: Using `0LL` may prevent integer overflow as the container arguments surely will be promoted to `long long` in this case when they are added to the internal accumulator.

Answer (score 2):

Functionally there's no difference at all but using Oll instead O will perform summation in long long and also will return result in long long, which will prevent integer overflow in case of large integer sums which exceed normal int range.